# How to prevent jstree from ordering the leafs in alphabetical order

Tags: jstree

I'm using a simple jstree with only three leafs. I should present them in the order set by backend, but the frontend automatically orders them to alphabetical order even though I'm not using sort plugin. Is there a way to prevent this behaviour ?

```
$(document).ready( function() {

$('#jstree2').jstree({
"core" : {
  "animation" : 0,
  "check_callback" : true,
  "themes" : { "stripes" : true },
  'data' : {
    "url" : "/api/all_graphs_in_json_for/",
    "dataType" : "json" // needed only if you do not supply JSON headers
  }      
},

"types" : {
  "#" : {
    "max_children" : 1,
    "max_depth" : 2,
    "valid_children" : ["root"]
  },
  "root" : {
    "icon" : "/static/3.3.4/assets/images/tree_icon.png",
    "valid_children" : ["default"]
  },
  "default" : {
    "valid_children" : ["default","file"]
  },
  "file" : {
    "icon" : "glyphicon glyphicon-file",
    "valid_children" : []
  }
},
"plugins" : [
  "search", 
  "types",
  "wholerow",
  "unique"
]             
});
```

Comment: If you are not using sort plugin, it shouldn't sort them in order. It should appear as the appear in the data array. Would it be possible to share the code snippet?

Comment: @Asif Nowaj just added my code...

Comment: Hi @Jaana, Thanks for the update. I have used your jsTree configuration with below json data but I can not replicate the issue on my end. Are you sure, your json data which is coming to client side are not already in sorted form? Can you put some your data snippet, masking your original data for confidential data.

Comment: @Asif Nowaj You were right. Thre really was on sort in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the update. I have used your jsTree configuration with below json data but I can not replicate the issue on my end. Are you sure, your json data which is coming to client side are not already in sorted form? Can you put some your data snippet, masking your original data for confidential data.

```
var jsondata = [
  { "id": "ajson1", "parent": "#", "text": "Simple root node" },
  { "id": "ajson2", "parent": "#", "text": "Root node 2" },
  { "id": "ajson3", "parent": "ajson2", "text": "Child 2" },
  { "id": "Child_1", "parent": "ajson2", "text": "Child 1" },
  { "id": "aaa", "parent": "ajson2", "text": "aaa" },
];
```

[image]